# finding file using two variables in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I need to know the command in shell script for finding out the filenames with one string and one variable where my **$arg** contains list of names that should be present on my file name and as well the specific text

```
prabhas 
surya 
jeeva 
raj
```

all these data will be looping in **$arg** and my string that needs to be matched is "hero" always and here are the filenames like

```
cinema_field_prabhas_hero.json
dialama_jeeva_tollywod_manupulation_hero.json
voiln_mentor_surya_xxx_yyy_hero_zzz.json
```

where the text will always be hero but my **$arg** will be changing so I need to find the files that have hero keyword and **$arg** that comes from looping, Please help me out

Comment: Which shell? Bash? Tag it. Also clarify your question - show pseudo code of what you're trying to do if you don't have any valid code. It's unclear what your trying. I suggest you look at [ask].

Comment: Also, are they all in the same directory? Is there a specific hierarchy. As of now this question it to unclear.

Comment: maprcli volume info -name nnclambda_$arg_hero -json | grep -i 'enableddata\|auditdata\|rowdata'  this is my command where my data should always have $arg somewher in the file like nnclambda_$arg and with the specific string and sometimes my json file is nnclambda_mahandt_$arg_hero and sometimes like nnclambda_$arg_hanagst_hero  but everywhere it will be snapshot and $arg for sure